# Get-Content of a file in powershell

Tags: powershell

The main picture is:
i want to store in a variable the content of a file that contains multiple lines. After storing it i have to be able to display the content of the variable on multiple lines.

for example the file contains:

```
word1 word2 word3

word4

word5 word6
```

And I then do:

```
$X=get-content \file.txt
```

get-variable X should return:

```
word1 word2 word3

word4

word5 word6
```

but i have no ideea how to load the file into variable and keep the formatting. I don't want to display all file content in the same line

Can you guys provide some hints for it please?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the formatting"? Also, `Get-Variable X` is unnecessary if you just want the value. Just use `$X` (or `Get-Variable X -ValueOnly` if you must)

Comment: formatting means that if i have 5 lines in the file, i want to display the variable as having 5 lines of text.

Comment: Then just type in `$X` and hit [enter] - what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that it displays all file content in one row and i want it as it was initially in the file (multiple lines).

Comment: the main goal is to get the content of a file (that contains 3 4 rows) and place it in a mail body without using HTML formating. Just put file content there. right now i have the file as attachment, but i need it as email body

Comment: ***Get-Variable x*** would return one line with the name and value of the variable. If you literally just type ***$x*** at the prompt as was suggested by Mathias R. Jessen then you get the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already:

## STOP USING [`GET-VARIABLE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849899.aspx) IF YOU ONLY NEED THE VALUE

Simply dereference the variable value with `$X`:

[image]

---

If you ever find yourself in a situation where you absolutely *must* use `Get-Variable` (e.g scope traversal), you'll want to use the `ValueOnly` parameter, or select the `Value` property from the object:

```
PS C:\> $ABC = 123
PS C:\> Get-Variable ABC -ValueOnly
123
PS C:\> Get-Variable ABC |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
123
```

Contrast with the full `PSVariable` object returned by `Get-Variable` without the `-ValueOnly` parameter:

```
PS C:\> $ABC = 123
PS C:\> Get-Variable ABC |Select-Object *

Name        : ABC
Description :
Value       : 123
Visibility  : Public
Module      :
ModuleName  :
Options     : None
Attributes  : {}
```